# How to find the SSH current local machine directory?

Tags: ssh, scp, local

I am attempting to upload a file from my local machine to my server using:

```
scp Users\MyName\Desktop\myzipfile.zip user@host:/path/to/whereyouwant/thefile
```

I have a Zip file on my desktop that I am trying to upload. My problem is I do not know what the local machine directory is when using SSH.

How can I know what it is? Meaning, how do I correctly write the path to my Zip file sitting on the desktop of my local machine?

I've tried every path I can think of.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

There is probably some environment variable pointing to your home:

```
scp $HOME\Desktop\myzipfile.zip user@host:/path/to/whereyouwant/thefile
```

But then you will have probably problem with `:` in the path. You can workaround it using:

```
cat $HOME\Desktop\myzipfile.zip | ssh user@host cat /path/to/whereyouwant/thefile
```

which is basically the equivalent using pure `ssh`. But make sure you have set-up passwordless authentication or control master, otherwise it will fail.

Comment: change the \ (backslash) with / (slash) in `$HOME\Desktop\myzipfile.zip` for *nix OS.

Comment: Yes, but from the backslashes it looks like windows question.

Comment: Yes sorry I am using Windows

Comment: Have you tried 
`scp \Users\MyName\Desktop\myzipfile.zip\ user@host:/path/to/whereyouwant/thefile` ?